# I am trying to read a csv file with pandas and then to search a string in the first column, to use total row for calculations

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am reading a CSV file with `pandas`, and then I try to find a word like "Net income" in the first column. Then I want to use the whole row which has this structure: string/number/number/number/... to do some calculations with the numbers.

The problem is that `find` is not working.

```
data = pd.read_csv(name)   
data.str.find('Net income')
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\thoma\Desktop\python programme\manage.py", line 16, in <module>
    data.str.find('Net income')
```

I am using CSV files from here: [Income Statement for Deutsche Lufthansa AG (DLAKF) from Morningstar.com](https://financials.morningstar.com/income-statement/is.html?t=0P0000BWKH&culture=en&ops=clear)

I found this: [Python | Pandas Series.str.find() - GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-series-str-find/)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\thoma\Desktop\python programme\manage.py", line 16, in <module>
    data.str.find('Net income')
  File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5067, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'
```

So, it works now. But I still have a question. After using the `describe` function with pandas I get this:

```
<bound method NDFrame.describe of 2014-12    615
2015-12    612
2016-12    636
2017-12    713
2018-12    736
Name: Goodwill, dtype: object>
```

I have problems to use the data. So how can I f.e. use the second column here? I tried to do a new table:

```
new_Table['Goodwill'] = data1['Goodwill'].describe
```

but this does not work.

I also would like to add more "second" columns to `new_Table`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you should filter the column name like df[‘col name’].str.find(x) this required a series not a data frame.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend setting your header row if pandas isnt recognizing named rows in your CSV file.

Something like:

```
new_header = data.iloc[0] #grab the first row for the header
data = data[1:] #take the data less the header row
data.columns = new_header
```

From there you can summarize each column by name:

```
data['Net Income'].describe
```

edit: I looked at the csv file, I recommend reshaping the data first before analyzing columns.Something like...

```
data=data.transpose
```

So in summation:

```
data = pd.read_csv(name)
data=data.transpose #flip the columns/rows
new_header = data.iloc[0] #grab the first row for the header
data = data[1:] #take the data less the header row
data.columns = new_header
data['Net Income'].describe #analyze
```

Comment: Thx. But it seems that the transpose function is not compatible with pandas, because it does not change the csv-file. I think thats why I get the failure:AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'iloc'

Comment: Hi, sorry, import Numpy package to use .transpose. See if that works.

Comment: Do you know, if it possible to do something to do collect the data from describe in a new table? Something like table_content[a]=data['Net Income'].describe and  table_content[b]=data['...'].describe.

Comment: try data['Net Income'].describe.to_csv("my_description.csv") to export the output